# Is it possible to implement vertical scroll bar in a drop down menu using CSS alone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to implement a vertical scroll in a drop down menu when the options in the menu exceed 8.Is it possible to achieve this by using Css properties alone?Please let me know how I should go about this

Answer (score 1):

That is absolutely possible using CSS. All you need to do is set a fixed height on the menu (so set the height to however tall 8 items is) and give it `overflow-y: auto`. This tells the browser that if the fixed height is exceeded, a vertical scrollbar should appear.

Comment: `overflow: scroll` *always* shows a scroll bar. `overflow-y: auto;` will make it appear only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Set an "overflow: auto" property on the containing div.  To collapse the div if it is less than 8 items then you will need to use the max-height: property.  It will not work for IE6 so use a [hack to get around IE6](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/).

Answer (score 0):

on your `ul li ul` add the height you want for example `height:80px;` and `overflow-y:auto;`